# How to remove installed packages

Tags: software-installation, mysql-workbench

I installed a 32 bit MySQL workbench packages. But I faced many problems and tried to find answers here ... then I've known that my Ubuntu is 64 bit ... and downloaded the version of MySQL for 64 bit.

When I've typed:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql_64_bit.deb
```

The system asked me to remove the oldest one so I typed:

```
teeba@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -r mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb
```

I've gotten the following:

```
dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
```

Can anyone give me the right way to install the right one and remove the oldest one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

The above command will displays all the packages that have the word `mysql`.From that you can find the exact one and then remove it by running,

```
sudo dpkg -P <packageName>
```

The below command does not remove  the installed `mysql` package,

```
teeba@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -r mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1204-i386.deb
```

Comment: the following error has been appeared with the first command : ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'accountsservice     install
acl      install
acpi-support     install
acpid     ' at line 1

Comment: i edited now.forgot to mention grep.

Comment: if i get "purge" then that means that the package has been removed successfully ??

Comment: please see the following img , I think there is something error >> [snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdes7q2boanzzil/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-12%2006%3A55%3A23.png)

Comment: run only `sudo dpkg -P mysql-workbench-community:i386` and then try to install your 64 bit mysql package.

Comment: I did that and removed mysql-workbench-community:i386 but when   i've installed 64 bits version i've got the same results as in 32 bits ::: please see this [snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yk09wa16xhesr7/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-12%2007%3A43%3A21.png)

Comment: I'm very sad x_____x :(

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it from the apt-get tool, after you add the repository for My

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-workbench
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Does it still give you errors?