# How to remove LAMPP packages?

Tags: mysql, php, lamp, mariadb

Used this question to install LAMPP:

[What's the easiest way to set up a LAMP stack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34/whats-the-easiest-way-to-set-up-a-lamp-stack)

Several problems have cropped up and I want to start over. How can I remove everything?

Tried the suggestions in several other answers given on Ask Ubuntu, including:

[uninstall mysql from 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776845/uninstall-mysql-from-ubuntu-16-04/777008)

[how to remove installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419928/how-to-remove-installed-packages)

[how do I remove the lamp stack so I can start over](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over)

But they did not work.  Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: "They did not work" is a bit vague. Can you please explain why they are inappropriate? Or describe how they failed? What is the complete error message?

Comment: Which of the commands did you use?